# ColdFusion is executing unwanted concurrent CFHTTP calls

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm building a ColdFusion app that pulls data from a 3rd party service and am running into an issue where CF is executing unwanted multiple concurrent calls to the same API endpoint. The API has a few limitations:

1. No concurrent calls to the same endpoint for a specific API user account
2. A limit of 500 results returned by the API per call, with a `nextPageUrl` value passed back for pagination

The data I'm trying to retrieve contains over 5000 records, so I'm pulling in 500 records at a time until the `nextPageUrl` returns `null` (per the API docs). I setup a page with the following code to test out the process:

```
<cffunction name="getAPIdata" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="yes">

    <cfset local.result = false>  
    <cfset local.apiUrl = "[INITIAL API CALL URL HERE]">
    <cfset local.apiCallComplete = false>

    <cfloop condition="local.apiCallComplete IS FALSE">

        <cfhttp url="#local.apiUrl#" method="get" result="local.res" throwOnError="no">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Credentials" value="[API USER CREDENtIALS HERE]">
        </cfhttp>

        <cfset local.data = deserializeJSON(local.res.fileContent)>

        <cfquery>
            <!--- Loop over local.data array and insert into db --->
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Write call results to log file and increment count (for testing) --->
        <cfif isDefined("local.data.nextPageUrl")>
            <cffile action="append" addnewline="true" file="#expandpath('../log.txt')#" output="Count: #count#">
            <cffile action="append" addnewline="true" file="#expandpath('../log.txt')#" output="Next page: #urlDecode(local.data.nextPageUrl)#">
            <cffile action="append" addnewline="true" file="#expandpath('../log.txt')#" output="-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------">
            <cfset count++>
            <cfset local.apiUrl = urlDecode(local.data.nextPageUrl)>
        <cfelse>
            <cffile action="append" addnewline="true" file="#expandpath('../log.txt')#" output="Count: #count#">
            <cffile action="append" addnewline="true" file="#expandpath('../log.txt')#" output="Next page: NONE">
            <cffile action="append" addnewline="true" file="#expandpath('../log.txt')#" output="-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------">
            <cfset local.result = true>
            <cfset local.apiCallComplete = true>
        </cfif>

    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn local.result>
</cffunction>
```

I initialize the count and call this function on the same page with:

```
<cfset count = 1>
<cfset getAPIdata()>
```

So in theory, it should loop - returning 500 records at a time - until all records have been retrieved. The weird thing is that as I watch the log.txt file, the count and next oage url values are logged twice:

```
Count: 1
Next page: https://... 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 1
Next page: https://... 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 2
Next page: https://... 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 2
Next page: https://... 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

etc.
```

I immediately get a warning email that I had exceeded the API thread threshold limit of one call to the same endpoint for this user, and duplicate records are inserted into the database. I tried putting the code inside the conditional loop in a `cflock` to see if that would keep this from happening, but while watching the log it would start to increment properly and then after the count hit 3 or so, it would add another incrementing series of calls starting at 1 in the middle of the existing loop, like:

```
Count: 1
Next page: https://...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 2
Next page: https://...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 3
Next page: https://...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 1
Next page: https://...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 2
Next page: https://...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 4
Next page: https://...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count: 3
Next page: https://...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


etc.
```

again triggering the warning email and duplicated database entries. My development stack is CF2018 behind Apache 2.4 with MySQL. Any ideas what may be causing this?

**UPDATE:**

I tested the original code on my production server running IIS and it works perfectly. Looks like this is an issue with Apache (possibly url rewrites) or something else in my dev environment rather than an issue with ColdFusion.

Comment: Running your function in a clean single request exactly returns what you expect. So the doubling is caused on your end. Isolate the problem by putting your function and those two lines in a separate .cfm file to test.

Comment: I added the function to a CFC component, invoked it from a separate cfm oage, and got the same logging result as shown above.

Comment: Hard to tell. Whats about isDefined("local.data.nextPageUrl")? Is it defined on that second doubled logged line? How is the returned data? Identical? Also, In any loop like that I'd always reset/initialize any data/variable at the top and then let it be repopulated, just to make sure it's not working with old data of the previous looped loop cycle.

Comment: How do you request your page? Make a minimal working example of your code and invoke it in a controlled matter. I did by mocking the cfhttp call and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your time with this. I tested the original code on my production server (IIS) and it worked perfectly. Looks like this is not a CF issue, but something with Apache (rewrites?) or my dev environment.

Comment: You should be able to chase the cause of the duplication back by a) looking at your logs (eg: the apache ones); b) logging more stuff. Log something inside the loop. Log something before the loop. Log something before the call to `getAPIdata`, etc, back upstream to the entry point of the CFML code. At some point, you'll start getting duplicates... that's where you need to look.